# Strange struts2 exceptions in Tomcat6 logs (There is no Action mapped for action name [some HTML Code!!!!].)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2

I have a webApplication(Java+Struts2+...) running on tomcat6.
I don't know what is the problem that the logs show this kind of exceptions:

```
WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for action name ><script src=. - [unknown location]

OR

There is no Action mapped for action name li><li><a href='. - [unknown location]

OR

There is no Action mapped for action name dth: 342,maxHeight: 400}). - [unknown location]

and more and more...!!!!
```

This is a sample of an exception stack trace:

```
May 18, 2012 12:28:48 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Could not find action or result
There is no Action mapped for action name ><script src=. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:178)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

What do you think the problem is?!
Or How can I find out more about this?!
Thanks buddies.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like attempts to find XSS vulnerabilities in your application. If so, be aware that somebody tries to attack your application.

Comment: @AminSh: It looks like a check whether attacker can inject a link into navigation menu of your page (hence `<li>`) and trick users into clicking it.

Comment: If that is the case I don't think you need to worry until you see struts2 reporting issues with setting parameters... as it is they are not even close to getting something to work =).  It might be interesting to have the logs report the session id (or the user id) of the user which is causing the issue. Probably set up a struts2 error handler would do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have entered script src=. at a place where a form action or an ajax url (i.e. action name) is expected and obviously there would not be an action named script src=. in your struts.xml file.